# QGIS Modeler - Select by expression error

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

QGIS Modeler works fine with my data if I store the layers as temporary layers, but soon as I will save the output in the selected folder (as shapefile or geopackage) I get a wrong result. The select by expresion is not working fine anymore.

The expresssion is: "AREA" != maximum("AREA")

[image]

The select by expresion is not working fine anymore

Comment: Should it not be `"AREA" != maximum('AREA')`?

Comment: You are right, I wrote it wrong here. Already corrected

Comment: An alternative could be to replace the _Select by expression_ and _Eliminate selected polygons_ tools by using the **Extract by expression** tool and then using the reverse of your expression (e.g. `"AREA" = maximum("AREA")`)? If this works then perhaps there is a bug with your initial method.